# Skype events listener for android

Tags: android, skype, skype4java

Is there any Skype listener in android?? like phoneStateListener which listen the events of phone call either it is in offhook, on call, idle state etc.

So, is there any listener for Skype in android by which we can detect the call events on skype either it is idle, offhook or something else??

I know there is lots of articles which says Skype doesn't provide any api access.

Please let me know if something which i can do to get the events for Skype.